# Aplicativo para gerenciar banco de dados em raspberry pi

Tags: java, android, mysql, app, ssh

Olá. Preciso desenvolver um aplicativo para Android, para fazer a extração e exclusão de um banco de dados mysql em um raspberry pi, estando na mesma rede. Pensei em fazer por ssh, porém, nunca desenvolvi algo para dispositivos móveis, e não tenho muita experiência com o Android Studio. Como posso iniciar este projeto?

Comment: Pergunta ampla demais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, João.

Sua pergunta é bem genérica. Na [wiki](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) da tag "android" aqui do StackOverflow em português tem alguns tutoriais (na parte de Tutoriais & Exemplos) bacanas e aconselho que os faça inicialmente para que você comece a ter um certo entendimento do Android antes de começar o seu projeto. Qualquer dúvidas que surgir durante o tutorial, crie perguntas aqui para te ajudarmos. Abs!

Comment: Obrigado! Vou começar procurando por lá!